# How to test a localized WPF application in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, languages, culture

I am trying to create a localized application in C# / WPF in Visual Studio 2012. For that I created two resource files and changed one string in a (XAML) window to use the resource files (instead of a hardcoded string).

I see the English text from the resource file, which is correct. However, I want to check if the other resource file (fr-FR) also works but I cannot find a setting or procedure how to change my 'project' to run in French.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been fond of the basic WPF "support" for localization.  I've been using this for over four years: [Advanced WPF Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249369/Advanced-WPF-Localization%20Advanced%20WPF%20Localization) (the "advanced" version is relatively new - I used the "simple" version up to about a year ago).  This implements a markup extension and allows you to localize text, images, brushes, etc.  It also supports changing language on the fly, which can be useful in some scenarios.